# Installing Lizmap with PostgreSQL and Azure

Tags: postgresql, installation, qgis-server, lizmap, azure

In our service we have already installed Lizmap on an Azure server, so it works fine but it's just with shp, GeoJSON files. I suggested to them that we work with a database that I created on a PostgreSQL Azure server, I know that I have to give the identifiers of the database server to the cartographic server, but I don't know how the work is done.

How do I do it?

Comment: Does your PostGIS layers works in QGIS first ? Either store login and password in QGS files or use a PostgreSQL service file to connect to the database.

Comment: Hello sorry for this late reply, yes the POSTGIS_QGIS connection is working fine, and I am connecting by entering the login and password, but I don't know how I can save them in the project file

Comment: If you enter credentials when you are opening QGIS, Lizmap won't be able to connect automatically to the postgres database. Right-click on your database, "edit connection", "store password". Then you must right-click on your layer, change datasource, and select your layer again. If you open your QGS file in a text editor, search your password, it must be there. Otherwise, to be more secure, use a PG service file.

Comment: hello, thank you very much I managed to establish the connection, it was due to the ticking of the save box, good day